# Beautifying URLs thru urlManager rules works one way only

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I followed this [tut](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/blog/en/final.url) (copy of [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters)) for creating custom rule for named parameters. In my rules array i've added 2 upper lines to parse backwards and forwards `Assortment[groupCategory]` parameter.

```
  'urlManager'=>array( 
        'showScriptName'=>false, 
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(      
             'assortment/<Assortment[groupCategory]:\d+>'=> 'assortment/index',
             'assortment/<Assortment%5BgroupCategory%5D:\d+>'=> 'assortment/index', 
             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', 
         ),
       ),
```

This works forward: 
with `http://tarex.ru/assortment/index/Assortment[groupCategory]/1` the yii recognize `Assortment[groupCategory]` as a GET parameter equal 1.

But if from a form i request

- `http://tarex.ru/assortment/index?Assortment[groupCategory]=2` or
- `http://tarex.ru/assortment/index?Assortment%5BgroupCategory%5D=2`

it does not transform it into the human readable ulr, like this:

`http://tarex.ru/assortment/index/Assortment[groupCategory]/2`

Why? The tut sais it's **two-way url manager**.

> On the other hand, when creating a URL with the route post/index and parameter tag, the urlManager component will also use this rule to generate the desired URL /index.php/posts/yii. For this reason, we say that urlManager is a two-way URL manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it does not transform it into the human readable ulr

Yes, Yii does not transform url in browsers address bar, nor in forms action parameter. Everything is run „behind scenes“.

I recommend you to rewrite your rule

```
'assortment/<Assortment[groupCategory]:\d+>'=> 'assortment/index'
```

to

```
'assortment/<groupCategory:\d+>'=> 'assortment/index'
```

In this way, if you go to url `http://tarex.ru/assortment/index/1` an `actionIndex()` method will be called in controller named `AssortmentController`. And parameter `$groupCategory = 1` will be passed to it. To handle passed variable you probably need to change methods signature to:

```
public function actionIndex( $groupCategory ) {}
```

The „back-way“ will be if you create url by getting parameters in this way:

```
echo Yii::app()->controller->createUrl( 'assortment/index', array( 'groupCategory' => 1 ) ) ;
```

a url `/assortment/index/1` must be created.

Comment: can i use `Assortment[groupCategory]`, the compound one, as parameter rather than `groupCategory`?

Comment: I'm afraid this `Assortment[groupCategory]` will work just „one-way“. Because when assigning value to `$Assortment[groupCategory]` you assign to array member. You know, brackets can not be used in PHP variable name. What is the reason to use them?

Comment: Or you can try `echo Yii::app()->controller->createUrl( 'assortment/index', array( 'Assortment[groupCategory]' => 1 ) ) ;`
:)

Comment: the `Assortment[groupCategory]` goes with Active Record ORM used in Yii. This is wrap up with [Models][http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model] and [Active Records][http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/database.ar] in Yii. But i'll try your suggestion. Wouldn't the rule that you suggested override the rule applied to `id` parameter: `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'` ?

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I broke thru with urls management.

Comment: In url manager **the first matching rule will bu esed**. So if you place specific rule above `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'` – the first one will take precedence.